# UWP: Exception "ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" for some specific target machines

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, classnotfound

I have the following code that in some sporadic target machines produce the following exception:

> ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040111)

This is the code that produces the exception:

```
WindowingEnvironment winEnv = WindowingEnvironment.FindAll(WindowingEnvironmentKind.Overlapped).FirstOrDefault();
if (winEnv == null)
    return;

IReadOnlyList<DisplayRegion> regions = winEnv.GetDisplayRegions();
List<string> monitorIds = new List<string>();
foreach (DisplayRegion region in regions)
{
    if (!region.IsVisible)
        continue;
    string monitorId = region.DisplayMonitorDeviceId;
    if (!monitorIds.Contains(monitorId))
    {
        monitorIds.Add(monitorId);
        Debug.WriteLine(region.WorkAreaSize.ToLTSize());
    }
}
```

This code works fine in all our development machines and in 99.9% of the user base, but in a few sporadic cases, it throws the above-mentioned exception. So, I guess it could be a problem of the target OS or some preferences of the user that would upset one of those APIs.

Please also note that the users experiencing this problem are running the latest Win 10 build.

Do you have any clue of which preferences/settings/etc. could affect this code?

Thank you!

Comment: There are lots of calls that potentially require the class factory to produce an object. Which one of those fails?

Comment: `WindowingEnvironment` is new for build 10.0.18362.0. Maybe some of your customers are running older builds?

Comment: @RaymondChen good point, but all the problems come from users with the latest Win10 version

Comment: When you received this exception? When you called the FindAll() method? Can you tell us which line of code caused this error?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT yes, usually the crash is at the FindAll

Comment: Whether the latest win10 vesion you mentioned is 2004? Does the problem only occur on those machines with 2004 version?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT as far as I can tell it happened on machines with the latest win10 version

Comment: Do you know the exact version number? The exact version number will help us locate the issue.